# swift firebase how add a new word to a list without deleting the previous word

Tags: swift, firebase

currently this app has a textfield and when you press return on the keyboard it displays the live data on the screen but It deletes the previous question. My question is how can I not delete the previous question and just add this new question to the list.. thank you so much !

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    let database = Firestore.firestore()
    
    private let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        return label
        
    }()
    
    private let field: UITextField = {
        let field = UITextField()
        field.placeholder = "enter text.."
        field.layer.borderWidth = 1
        field.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        return field
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(label)
        view.addSubview(field)
        field.delegate = self

        let docRef = database.document("ios/ex")
        docRef.addSnapshotListener {[weak self] snapshot, error in
            guard let data = snapshot?.data(), error == nil else {
                return
            }
            
            guard let text = data["text"] as? String else {
                return
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.label.text = text
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        field.frame = CGRect(x: 1, y: view.safeAreaInsets.top+10, width: view.frame.size.width-20, height: 50)
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 1, y: view.safeAreaInsets.top+10+60, width: view.frame.size.width-20, height: 100)
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if let text = textField.text, !text.isEmpty {
            savedData(text: text)
        }
        return true
    }
    
    func savedData(text: String){
        let docRef = database.document("ios/ex")
        docRef.setData(["text": text])
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What list? It looks like you dont have anything that can hold a list.  Label is meant for a single field of text. Same with a text field. You would need some type of list component such as a UITableView or UITextView that is meant to display multiple lines of text. You could also create a reusable component that has a UILabel in it and add it to the view when you get a new question.

Answer (score 1):

In my interpretation of what you are trying to do is that you are returning some string in your textfield and have that appear on your UILabel when the Firestore listener sees the change in the data. But the problem is, your previous data is not appearing. This is because of this function:

```
func savedData(text: String){
    let docRef = database.document("ios/ex")
    docRef.setData(["text": text])
}
```

What "docRef.setData()" does is it replaces the existing data with the new data you are setting. That is why you are losing your previous data.

If you want to append the text to the previous question which is displayed on your label, you might want to save that label string and append your text and then update the data:

```
func savedData(text: String){
    let previousString = self.label.text!
    let newString = previousString + text
    let docRef = database.document("ios/ex")
    docRef.updateData(["text": newString])
}
```